# Set a Date Range in AngularJS and Kendo DatePickers

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 Kendo Datepickers on a HTML page :

```
                        <kendo-date-picker 
                                          name="StartDate"
                                          ng-model="data.StartDate">
                        </kendo-date-picker>


                        <kendo-date-picker 
                                          name="EndDate"
                                          ng-model="data.EndDate">
                        </kendo-date-picker>
```

I need to set their initial dates from my AngularJS controller to :
StartDate = today and EndDate = a year from StartDate.

I do I go about acheiving this?

Comment: Please read the documentation. [Link](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/datepicker/how-to/AngularJS/range-selection)

Comment: Thanks will take a look,

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you need to write

$scope["data"]["StartDate"] = new Date(); // This will set the current date

var yearLaterDate = currentDate.setFullYear(currentDate.getFullYear()+1);

$scope["data"]["EndDate"] = new Date(yearLaterDate); // Date after one year